# Interchangeable NONCLUSTERED and UNIQUE index on a same column

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have these two indexes on a table and I wonder whether they are interchangeable?
The thing is that when I look at the usage statistics I see that both are being used.

What will happen if I delete `IX_clicks_token`? Will `uc_token` be used instead?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_clicks_token] ON [dbo].[clicks]
(
    [token] ASC
)


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[clicks] ADD  CONSTRAINT [uc_token] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [token] ASC
)


OBJECT NAME     |   IX_clicks_token --- uc_token
user_seeks      |   0 --- 12
user_scans      |   10500 --- 298
user_lookups    |   0 --- 0
user_updates    |   582272 --- 582272
last_user_seek  |   NULL --- 2013-03-24
last_user_scan  |   2013-03-25 --- 2013-03-20
```

Comment: what does the execution plan say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IX_clicks_token` and `uc_token` have almost identical definitions, with the only different being that `uc_token` enforces uniqueness as well as providing a non-clustered index.

If you delete `IX_clicks_token`, `uc_token` SHOULD be used instead, assuming that there's not some weird edge case where the remaining index is super fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

Both are equivalent. Probably, they are just both being used due to random optimizer choices in case of identical alternatives.

Remove one of them. Doesn't really matter, which. It might be the case that you can't drop one but drop the other - in that case the choice is taken for you.